# How can I improve the performance of this "iterrows()" function logic?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a "reporting" Dataframe called `report_df` instantiated, its role is to collect results of a comparison between two other Dataframes - `df_a` and `df_b`. You can assume its scope is global and that the reporting dataframe is derived from `df_a` (which is why we use the index in the compare `function` logic).

The comparison code is orchestrated through the loop seen below:

```
for idx, row in df_a.iterrows():
    compare(df_b, row, df_a_col, df_b_col, idx)
```

The `compare` function is shown below.

```
def compare(df_b, row, df_a_col, df_b_col, idx):
    matching_rows = df_b[df_b[df_b_col].astype(str) == str(row[df_a_col])]
    
    if len(matching_rows) > 0:
        # Get first matching row only.
        matching_row = matching_rows.head(1)
        # tell then reporting dataframe we found a match
        report_df.loc[idx, "match"] = True

        # Update the "match_index" only if "match_how" is "unmatched"
        if report_df.at[report_df.index[idx], 'match_how'] == 'unmatched':
           report_df.loc[idx, "match_index"] = matching_row.index[0]
```

My question is, is there a way that this function logic can become a vectorised process to improve performance? as I am scaling my data, the loop is increasingly becoming less performant.

**NOTE**: Scenario has been simplified to the bare minimum to enable ease of interpretation - some context is lost due to this but the operations I am performing in the function remain the same.

Comment: I think **for idx, value in enumerate(df_a[df_a_col].values)** is better than **iterrows** if you use only **df_a_col** value from **df_a**

Comment: "as I am scaling my data, the loop is increasingly becoming less performant." Well, yes; every call to `compare` has to process the entire DataFrame as it currently is at that point in the process. Could you explain the intended overall logic in more detail? For example, show a small example input `df_a` and `df_b`, and the exact expected corresponding output?